# How can we debug ASP.NET MVC web application in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code

Microsoft just released [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) a couple of days ago.

How can we debug an ASP.NET MVC applications from within that IDE?

Comment: See [Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/debugging) and  [_"Visual Studio Code and ASP.NET 5 are in preview and at this time debugging is not supported on OS X and Linux. Rest assured, we are working hard to bring these experiences to you in the near future."_](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/aspnet5). What do _you_ mean by "ASP.NET MVC" and on what platform do you want to debug?

Comment: As you know, Microsoft published their source code at https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/dev/samples/1.0.0-beta4/HelloMvc. I can run that app, but I cannot use Visual Studio Code Debug function. I try to debug it but it always notified that only can run debug with .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (in this preview release). See: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/aspnet5

Comment: Yes, I know. But when I tried to debug it on Windows machine, it was not support too.

Answer (score 16):

## Install the C# Extension

Open vscode and install the C# Extension.

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- `ext install csharp`
- Click Install.
- After install, click Enable and restart vscode.

[image: ext install csharp]

## Add launch.json and tasks.json

Open your project's directory in vscode. File > Open Folder...

Vscode might ask: *Required assets to build and debug are missing from your project. Add them?*

[image: Required assets...]

If so, choose **Yes**. This will add a `.vscode` directory with a `launch.json` and `tasks.json` file.

Note: If vscode does not ask this, you must ensure those files have the appropriate settings. One way to do that is to delete the existing `.vscode` directory and then restart vscode.

## Debug

Open the Debug View (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>), choose a configuration, and click the green arrow. If you aren't sure which configuration to choose, use .NET Core Launch (web).

[image: Debug view...]

If you're setup properly, the web browser will open at localhost:5000 and the DEBUG CONSOLE will display output.

## launch.json notes

This works for an EXE in `net451`.

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}\\bin\\Debug\\net451\\myApp.exe",
```

This works for a DLL in `netcoreapp1.0`.

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp1.0\\myApp.dll",
```

## program.json notes

Enable portable PDBs by adding the following entry. Otherwise you will receive the "No symbols have been loaded for this document" message.

```
"buildOptions: {
    "debugType": "portable",
}
```

## See also

- https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger.md
- https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp

Comment: Thanks for your very details answer. I think at the moment, VS Code already supported debug on the Windows OS. This answer is very old in very first release of VS Code 1 year ago.

Comment: @thangchung Are you saying that we no longer need to install the C# extension?

Comment: "One way to do that is to delete the existing .vscode directory and then restart vscode" ... helped me greatly!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: worked first time, great steps, thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **windows environment** then you have to `configure actions` and add breakpoints, similar to visual studio and then use <kbd>F5</kbd>. See following image,

[image]

More info [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/debugging)

Comment: Yes, I know that. But it only support for debug js files :(

Comment: I didn't tried it on .NET application, but similar keys should work. Did you gave it a try?

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstood, but I could not know what is `similar keys`?

Comment: It notified `Unable to create 'launch.json' file inside the '.settings' folder.`

Comment: Give me some time, I'll try to create a new .NET application and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw the "Required assets to build and debug are missing from [project name].  Add them?" in Visual Studio Code

[image: required assets missing]

There should be a choice to display the "assets" it is talking about adding.  These "assets" were added previously (yesterday when I created the project) and are only not showing up now because I've restarted my computer.  It's a bit confusing.

If you click the gear icon on the right side,and then select the menu item (Manage Extension) that appears, then you'll see the asset it is talking about:

[image: target asset shown]

Here's the info on current version of Visual Studio Code and dependencies...

Visual Studio Code Version: 1.44.2
Commit: ff915844119ce9485abfe8aa9076ec76b5300ddd
Date: 2020-04-16T17:50:03.709Z
Electron: 7.1.11
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130 
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.3.0-51-generic

[image: about Visual Studio code]