# Possibility of Debugging ASP .Net MVC Applications(Not .Net Core) using visual studio code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have been reading several blogs, and found debugging steps for ASP.NET Core applications using Visual Studio Code editor. But I need to know about debugging ASP.NET MVC(3,4,5) applications using VS Code - the ASP.NET MVC versions before ASP.NET Core.

I know very well about working & debugging in Visual Studio (2015, 2017). But I would like know about that debugging support in Visual Studio Code for ASP.NET MVC apps and it support versions.

Comment: You can check this in below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027201/how-can-we-debug-asp-net-mvc-web-application-in-visual-studio-code#:~:text=Open%20the%20Debug%20View%20(%20CTRL,DEBUG%20CONSOLE%20will%20display%20output.