# Running .NET Framework 4.7.2 project created in Visual Studio in VSCode IDE

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

I would like to use VSCode to work on a .NET Framework project that I will soon be given.  I'm trying to determine if I'll be able to do so or if I'll need to use Visual Studio 2022.  To test this, I created a new project in Visual Studio.  I ran it in Visual Studio and it runs fine.  I added some text on the default.aspx page just to be sure and all is magnificent.

So then I opened the same folder in VSCode and tried to run it with the "Launch Chrome against localhost" debugging option.  I realized I didn't have IIS turned on or have IIS Express on my machine.  I had the help desk turn on IIS in control panel (new at this company so they don't give me admin rights to the machine yet) and they also installed IIS Express.  I also installed the Warren Buckley IIS Express extension in VSCode.  The settings.json file looks like this

[image: image of settings.json file]

However, I try to debug with the "Launch Chrome against localhost" debugging option, I get this.

[image: image of problem when running in Chrome]

Not sure if it's related but I notice my csproj file is shown in red in the explorer panel.  Past experience tells me that means there's some problem with this file, but no problems are listed.
[image: image showing file in red but no problems reported in workspace]

At this point I'm beginning to wonder if it's even possible to run a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project in VSCode.  So that's my two questions -- is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?  And if so, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I debug .NET MVC project with VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66426716/how-can-i-debug-net-mvc-project-with-vs-code)

Comment: It looks like it very much will, thanks!  I won't know for sure until I get the help desk to add things to my path but this looks promising.  I'll come back and let you know if I have any issues.  And THANKS a billion!!!!